# Multisort Python

Tags: python, sorting, blender

I'm trying to write a custom exporter for Blender in Python. However, I'm having some trouble figuring out how I could use Python's native sort implementation to sort my vertices in the way I need.

Basically, I need to export the vertices in such a way where they can form a grid like this, assuming that V is a double.

```
V V V V V
V V V V V
V V V V V
V V V V V
```

The "engine" that I'm writing automatically retrieves the X and Z value of the coordinate based on where it is in the vertex map shown above. The V represents the Y coordinate. So this 5 by 5 map of vertices would create a 4 by 4 faced mesh.

However, in Blender, vertices appear to be ordered individually for each face of a mesh, rather in a format like mine. So, in order to export it, I need to order the coordinates first by depth (Y coordinate in Blender) and then by width (X coordinate in Blender). It would have to behave like a SQL query, where the first paramter given takes precedence in order compared to the second.

Here is what my code currently looks like

```
#!BPY

"""
Name: 'VaV Export'
Blender: 269
Group: 'Export'
Tooltip: 'Export to VaV file format'
"""
import Blender
import bpy

class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY

    def sortX(self, other):
        if posX < other.posX:
            return 1

    def sortY(self, other):
        if posY < other.posY:
            return 1



def write(filename):
    out = open(filename, "w")
    terraindata = bpy.data.meshes["Terrain"]
    vertices = terraindata.vertices
    vertices = sorted(vertices, key = lambda x: x.co.y, reverse = True)
    vertices = sorted(vertices, key = lambda x: x.co.x, reverse = False)
    print(vertices)

Blender.Window.FileSelector(write, "Export")
```

The first call to sorted() successfully orders it according to depth (Y). However, The 2nd call to sorted messes up the order (as expected). How could I amend this to allow both sorts to occur without the 2nd messing up the first?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
vertices = sorted(vertices, key = lambda x: x.co.y, reverse = True)
```

to

```
vertices = sorted(vertices, key = lambda x: (x.co.y, x.co.x), reverse = True)
```

...and that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to order your vertices by decreasing `y` coordinate, with coordinates with equal `y` values ordered by increasing `x` coordinate. If that's right, you can return a tuple `(-x.co.y, x.co.x)` from your `key` function to `sorted` and Python will do both the whole sorting at once.

An alternative would be to take a page from [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and sort by least-significant coordinate (e.g. `x`) first, then by the more significant coordinate (`y`). This will work since Python's `sort` is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I'm unsure as to what a tuple is as this is my first time working with Python. Do you have any sample code that I could look at?

Comment: Tuples are one of the basic [sequence data types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) in Python (see also, [this part](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of the tutorial). They're a lot like lists, but immutable (you can't modify them after they're created). You make a tuple by using commas in your code (e.g. `a,b`), though in some places like function arguments and lambda return values you may need to add a set of parentheses around the tuple values to avoid ambiguity (e.g. `func((a,b))` or `lambda x: (-x.co.y, x.co.x)`).